# cropping part of number as new variable

Tags: shell, variables, cut

I have a variable mydate and mydate=20141210.

I want to have another variable date set to 201412, which basically is mydate with the last 2 digits cropped off.  How do I do this in shell script?

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
mydate_cropped=$(echo $mydate | sed 's/..$//')
```

Here, `echo $mydate` pipes the content of `mydate` to `sed`, which uses replacement command (`s/regexp/replacement/`) to substitute two any symbols (`..`) at the and of the string (`$`) by empty string. Then, the cropped string is saved in the `mydate_cropped` variable.

Comment: if you would explain more about how/why this works it would be a better answer

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you shell has built-in parameter evaluation (all but csh), you can do

```
  mydate_cropped=${mydate%??}
```

or you can use it in-place, i.e.

```
  echo ${mydate%??}
  201412
```

The benefit here is fewer processes to make the truncation.

IHTH